# Rewrite negative number into positive numbers

Tags: views

I'm preparing some charts, with positive and negative values.
I would like to create one pie chart, including all the values (the positive and negative). Of course, this doesn't work as only positive numbers should be considered.
So I tried to rewrite the results (to cancel the "-") but it doesn't work. I would like to have "-100" displayed as "100", and the "100" staying at "100", so that I can create my graph.

Does somebody has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Drupal 7 you could use the `Global: Math expression` field to perform a mathematical operation. Load the initial field first, suppress it from display and use the replacement token within the Math field: (`abs([initial_field])`).

For Drupal 8 this field does not exist (yet), though there is a sandbox linked in post #10 here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2544670. It might work.

Comment: Awesome! You can use the check symbol (✓) left of the answer to mark it as solved :)